Installed php8.3.10 successfully on a fresh installation of headless ubuntu22.04, or did I?
I am using this guide to install php8.3.10 on Ubuntu22.04: https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.nginx.php
got to step 8 create a test file,
modified the given command:
echo "" >> /usr/local/nginx/html/index.php
to:
echo "" >> /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.php
output:
-bash: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.php: Permission denied
troubleshooting ps aux for both processes
input: ps aux | grep php-fpm
output: root        5764  0.0  0.0  86676  6920 ?        Ss   21:45   0:00 php-fpm: master process (/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf)
www-data    5765  0.0  0.1  86984  9424 ?        S    21:45   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data    5766  0.0  0.1  86984  9424 ?        S    21:45   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
user         5865  0.0  0.0   6480  2100 pts/0    S+   21:49   0:00 grep --color=auto php-fpm
input: ps aux | grep nginx
output: root         811  0.0  0.0  12076  5748 ?        Ss   17:50   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
www-data    4407  0.0  0.0  12860  4460 ?        S    20:38   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    4408  0.0  0.0  12860  4460 ?        S    20:38   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    4409  0.0  0.0  12860  4460 ?        S    20:38   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data    4410  0.0  0.0  12860  4460 ?        S    20:38   0:00 nginx: worker process
user         5882  0.0  0.0   6480  2204 pts/0    S+   21:49   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
so both programs are run as the same user www-data, how can permissions be denied?

"modified the given command" I'm confused, did you think that you could arbitrarily change the instructions, and it would still work? How would nginx know to look there for the content?

The problem with permissions above is when you try to edit index.php file inside /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.php, it's probably owned by root user or some other user
To check file permissions for that file you can do
ls -al /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.php

which will print out file permissions, owner and group, check if those match with the user you are using
If not and you need it to match, you can do
chmod user_that_should_use_file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.php
chown user_group /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/index.php

the ps aux | grep nginx will print out all currently running nginx processes which won't explain why the file itself is not accessible

Also there is no need to put index.php files in the /etc directory, if you followed the whole setup through and used /usr/local/nginx/ sticking to it will make sure everything works and you don't get errors

I'm now realizing how badly I botched the install, I'm trying again, thanks for the reply.
